# need older version of Google Mobile Ads SDK iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am in the need of older version of Google Mobile Ads SDK iOS may be 7.7.0 or older. Please share if anyone has it. I need to work on Xcode 6.3.2 and iOS 8.3. but latest version needs iOS 9 or later.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is looking for the answer to this question, as I was today... Here is a solution that incorporates Nika's fine answer and gives you a standalone solution for closed-source frameworks like these.

The Cocoapods specs need to be public and if you go to where those specs are published, in this case:  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/5/9/a/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK

You'll find a list of all the versions of Google Mobile Ads published via Cocoapods.

Each spec contains a download link, so [the spec for version `7.59.0` of the SDK / framework](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/5/9/a/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/7.59.0/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK.podspec.json) shows that link to be https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/de07064cf20bb7a6/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK-7.59.0.tar.gz

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem yourself mate:

**Step 1:** learn cocoapods. Cocoapods are used to integrate 3rd party libraries. It usually stores many many versions of the same libraries. There are plenty of tutorials on this under 10 minutes on youtube.

**Step 2:** import the version of google mobile ads library you need like this `pod 'GoogleMobileAds', '~> 7.7'`